# How to iterate over a non-linear container

Tags: c++, stl

Consider a hierarchical tree structure, where an item may have sibling items (at the same level in the hierarhcy) and may also have children items (one level down in hierarchy).

Lets say the structure can be defined like:

```
// an item of a hierarchical data structure
struct Item {
    int          data;     // keep it an int, rather than <T>, for simplicity
    vector<Item> children;
};
```

I wanted to be able to use algorithms over this structure, like the algorithms for a std::map, std::vector, etc. So, I created a few algorithms, like:

```
template <class Function>
Function  for_each_children_of_item( Item, Function f );  // deep (recursive) traversal

template <class Function>
Function  for_each_direct_children_of_item( Item, Function f );  // shallow (1st level) traversal

template <class Function>
Function  for_each_parent_of_item( Item, Function f );  // going up to the root item
```

One thing that troubled me is that there are 3 `for_each()` functions for the same structure. But they give a good description of how they iterate, so I decided to live with it.

Then, soon, the need for more algorithms emerged (like `find_if`, `count_if`, `any_of`, etc), which made me feel I'm not on the right track, design-wise.

One solution I can think of, that would reduce the workload, would be to simply write:

```
vector<Item>  get_all_children_of_item( Item );         // recursive
vector<Item>  get_all_direct_children_of_item( Item );  // 1st level items
vector<Item>  get_all_parents_of_item( Item );          // up to the root item
```

and then I could use all the STL algorithms. 
I am a bit wary of this solution, because it involves copying.

I cannot think of a way to implement an `iterator`, as there is no obvious `end()` iterator in the recursive version of the traversal.

- Can anybody present a typical / idiomatic way to deal with such *non-linear* data structures ?
- Can/should iterators be created for such a structure? how?

Comment: `std::map` takes the iterator route. It _does_ work with trees, but I'm not an expert at Google job interviews so I don't have any useless tree algorithms memorised right now. :) Your intuition is correct, in that you want a view over the data, not a copy of it. So I'd focus on working out how to work your way from left-to-right in a tree. :)

Comment: Yes, iterators are appropriate here. That's how you apply algorithms to the contents of `std::map`, for example, even though it's implemented as a binary tree. There's no need to copy the data; just write the appropriate code for the traversal in the increment operator.

Comment: Map can be iterated because it has pointer to parent node. Can that be done without adding extra data to the struct? I cannot change this part of the code.

Comment: For a `std::map`, the tree is hidden from the user. For iteration, it behaves like a "flat" container (e.g. like a linked list). If you want to iterate over all nodes in your tree similar to `std::map`, you could take a look at libstdc++'s [`_Rb_tree_increment`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/tree_8cc-source.html) which implements the iteration for `std::map`.

Comment: You might want to look at [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html). Perhaps you could just use it directly, or maybe just study its approach to graph traversal and do something similar.

Comment: @Grim If you can't change the struct you may have to store extra state in the iterator - e.g. all the `Item`s in the path from the root to where you are.

Comment: @AlanStokes this sounds promising, but could you please explain what would this state variable be? Jossutis mentions that *an iterator should not know whether it has reached the end of a container*. To me, this implies that iterators should not know much about other 'nodes' of the data structure other than their current one. But if we are to iterate recursively, then the iterator should remember each parent up the hierarchy we've descended, so it can go up one level, after it has finished with that branch

Comment: @Grim I'm not entirely sure I agree with that suggestion in general (but I don't know the context). An iterator definitely needs enough information to know how to get to the next element though - that's what it's for - which is what you and I both seem to be saying.

Answer (score 1):

Use iterators.

> I cannot think of a way to implement an iterator, as there is no obvious end() iterator in the recursive version of the traversal.

`end()` can be any designated special value for your iterator class as long as your increment operator produces it when stepping past the last element. And/or override operator `==`/`!=` for your iterator.

If you want to be really robust, implement an iterator mode for each of the [XPath axes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes).

Comment: So, you mean I should create a separate iterator for child-to-parent axis, another for item-to-all_children axis, etc ? Doesn't that mean that the structure itself should have pointers from children to parent, and from item to next (or previous) sibling ? It seems that there should be quite a lot of internal linking, just for having an iterator. Iterators are meant to be separating coupling between data structure and algorithms, but this is shifting an excessive burden to the data structure, itself...

Comment: Since you mentioned already having `get_all_parents_of_item`, I assumed you already had such parent linkage. If not, no need to support those axes.